# Copy XML attributes PHP

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I need to work with XML documents and I need to copy some fields to another XML file.
I have this field:

```
<cast>
    <person name="Nanda Anand" character="" job="Director" id="589088" thumb="" department="Directing" url="http://www.themoviedb.org/person/589088" order="0" cast_id="1000"/>
    <person name="Lynn Collins" character="" job="Actor" id="21044" thumb="http://cf2.imgobject.com/t/p/w185/berS11tKvXqTFThUWAYrH279cvn.jpg" department="Actors" url="http://www.themoviedb.org/person/21044" order="0" cast_id="1001"/>
</cast>
```

I need to copy all the elements to the another XML but with the attributes data..
I use this code, but it doesn't work:

```
foreach ($movies->movies->movie->cast->children() as $person)
            {
            $person = $cast->appendChild(
                    $xmldoc->createElement(("person"), str_replace("&", "&amp;",$person)));
            }
```

Comment: "It doesn't work" is about the most useless piece of information you could give. What does not work? How do you know it does not work? Do you get error-messages?

Comment: I'm sorry. I mean, it just copies a <person/> for each person it finds on the structure. I need to copy the attributes too. 
Can you help me now?

Comment: So bad u just comment to see a mistake from my side. You should think about we are here to help each other.

Comment: Heh, perhaps you could consider that I have other stuff to do :) From your comments at RageZ's answer I gather you're using simpleXML. Simple XML has no appendChild method. The answer provided by William Walseth (Use DomDocument and its methods) seems like a good idea to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to manipulate an XML document (ie adding nodes from one document to another), you should be using DOMDocument, not SimpleXML.

Here's some code to copy from one document to another using DOMDocument.  Note, it's a two step process.   First import the node into the document as $ndTemp.  Second, append the imported $ndTemp to a specified parent (I just use the root documentElement, but it could be another node).

NOTE: if you're just doing a simple copy, you may want to consider using XSL, but that's another post...

Input XML (movie.xml)

```
<xml>
<movie name='first'>
    <cast>
        <person name="Nanda Anand" character="" job="Director" id="589088" thumb="" department="Directing" url="http://www.themoviedb.org/person/589088" order="0" cast_id="1000"/>
        <person name="Lynn Collins" character="" job="Actor" id="21044" thumb="http://cf2.imgobject.com/t/p/w185/berS11tKvXqTFThUWAYrH279cvn.jpg" department="Actors" url="http://www.themoviedb.org/person/21044" order="0" cast_id="1001"/>
    </cast>
</movie>
<movie name='Second'>
    <cast>
        <person name="Zaphod Beeblebrox" character="" job="Director" id="589088" thumb="" department="Directing" url="http://www.themoviedb.org/person/589088" order="0" cast_id="1000"/>
    </cast>
</movie>
</xml>
```

PHP

```
<?php
    $xml = new DOMDocument();
    $strFileName = "movie.xml";
    $xml->load($strFileName);

    $xmlCopy = new DOMDocument();
    $xmlCopy->loadXML( "<xml/>" );

    $xpath = new domxpath( $xml );
    $strXPath = "/xml/movie/cast/person";

    $elements = $xpath->query( $strXPath, $xml );
    foreach( $elements as $element ) {
        $ndTemp = $xmlCopy->importNode( $element, true );
        $xmlCopy->documentElement->appendChild( $ndTemp );
    }
    echo $xmlCopy->saveXML();

?>
```

Output

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml>
    <person name="Nanda Anand" character="" job="Director" id="589088" thumb="" department="Directing" url="http://www.themoviedb.org/person/589088" order="0" cast_id="1000" />
    <person name="Lynn Collins" character="" job="Actor" id="21044" thumb="http://cf2.imgobject.com/t/p/w185/berS11tKvXqTFThUWAYrH279cvn.jpg" department="Actors"
    url="http://www.themoviedb.org/person/21044" order="0" cast_id="1001" />
    <person name="Zaphod Beeblebrox" character="" job="Director" id="589088" thumb="" department="Directing" url="http://www.themoviedb.org/person/589088" order="0" cast_id="1000" />
</xml>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this would work, not tested though

```
foreach ($movies->movies->movie->cast->children() as $person)
{
   $cast->appendChild($person);
}
```

Comment: thanks but.. seems like it is not working.
before this I crate this:
`$cast = $root->appendChild(
                            $xmldoc->createElement("cast"));`

don't know if u can use that info to give me a hand!

Comment: @Max: if you have to use createElement you will have to copy attributes by hand.

Comment: See, I create a Root element <movies/> where I add every <movie/>. In every <movie/> I need to add a <cast/> with a collection of <person/>. that's why I create that Element "cast".. what can I do to copy in that <cast/> "parent" all the <person/> form the $movies including the attributes???

Comment: If I use your code, the error says: "Argument 1 passed to DOMNode::appendChild() must be an instance of DOMNode, instance of SimpleXMLElement given"