# What is a good way to change/replace elements in a php+css document?

Tags: php, file-io

Forgive me for possibly misusing certain terminology. I would like to:

1. open a html/php file, with php
2. find elements with certain class
3. change its innerHtml basically
4. than save the file.

I have a feeling DOMElement in php could help, since I've used it for similar things in javascript, but I am (still) unsure of its function in PHP and php.net sais a DOM document `"Represents an entire HTML or XML document"` (so no php/javascript containing document).

- So: which function(s), libraries should I study to best perform those operations?
- Possibly: Aside from php.net do you perhaps have a good tutorial for ^that^ solution?

---

**Edit:** Possibly related: [Manipulate HTML from php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427239/manipulate-html-from-php)
**Edit2:** If I would build something with my knowledge a.t.m. it would probably be almost as violent as solutions I tried earlier: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8960363/574700

- There will be php in the document.
- There will be some inline css and javascript in there.

Comment: Unsure why I received -1. I tried to be specific and ask a clear question.

Comment: probably cause some people here expect to see code in every question. A way of showing that you tried something before asking. I don't know. Seems like a valid question to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.open a html/php file, with php

Include [htmlsimpledom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm) and open you php file.

```
$html = file_get_html('myfile.html');
```

2.find elements with certain class

```
foreach($html -> find('.class-name') as $element) 
       $element - > plaintext. '<br>';
```

3.change its innerHtml basically

```
$html -> find('.class-name') -> innertext = 'text-here';
```

4.then save the file.

```
file_put_contents($filename, $html);
```